# Is there a way to drop a range value from a partition table (sql server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-partitioning

I have a PARTITION table "TableA".
I created a partition on column name "RecorDate" (DATE type).
There are records from the last 6 months that I am not interested to save them, and I want to drop them.

Is there a simple way to drop a range vale OR specific partition number (or even a all range, for example '01-01-2014' to '01-01-2015').

something like in ORACLE, `TRUNCATE TABLE WITH(PARTITION(x,y to z))`.

BTW
I know the switch partition command, to move the range to another table and then exec the command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TableNameb ;
GO
```

10X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[TRUNCATE WITH PARTITION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570%28v=sql.130%29.aspx) will be available with SQL Server 2016**

> WITH ( PARTITIONS ( {  |  } [ ,
>   ...n ] ) )
>
> ```
> Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2 (CTP2) through current version).
>
> Specifies the partitions to truncate or from which all rows are removed. If the table is not partitioned, the WITH PARTITIONS argument
> ```
>
> will generate an error. If the WITH PARTITIONS clause is not provided,
>   the entire table will be truncated.
>
> ```
> <partition_number_expression> can be specified in the following ways:
>
>     Provide the number of a partition, for example: WITH (PARTITIONS (2))
>
>     Provide the partition numbers for several individual partitions separated by commas, for example: WITH (PARTITIONS (1, 5))
>
>     Provide both ranges and individual partitions, for example: WITH (PARTITIONS (2, 4, 6 TO 8))
>
>     <range> can be specified as partition numbers separated by the word TO, for example: WITH (PARTITIONS (6 TO 8))
> ```

Example:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.PartitionedTable WITH (PARTITIONS (2, 4, 6 TO 8))
```

**SQL Server before 2016**

Today you can use [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774012/truncate-partition):

> As you note, there is a way to do this today by moving the partition to a second table through **ALTER TABLE SWITCH** and then **TRUNCATE** the second table. If both tables are part of the same filegroup, this should actually be a low-risk operation as no data is moved, we just update the metadata.

[Example TABLE SWITCH](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/dejan_sarka/archive/2014/04/06/alter-table-switch-partition-ddl-or-dml.aspx)

Comment: what is the full command for a spasific partition(number) or range . If you can send me a link .

Comment: @itzikPaz Sorry, don't understand what you meam. All links are already in my answer.

Comment: @itzikPaz So simply create second table in the same filegroup and structure as partitioned table, SWITCH TABLE and truncate new table. That's all.

Comment: OK. Thanks. As I wrote in my question, I already know with this option. I thought that there are other options that I don't familiar with.

Comment: Another Question On the same Subject . After the SWITCH PARTITION from TableA to TableB . The switched Partition Number that moved(He Is An EMPTY Range) is still exists in The "OLD" table TableA. Is there a way to delete it ?

Comment: @itzikPaz If you want to remove one range, you can [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186307.aspx)  it `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionFunctionName()
MERGE RANGE (Boundary Value);`

Answer (score 0):

i would say delete * from table_name. delete all from table.
you can use the where statement after delete to be more precise.
to adjust the command yourself look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the solution I wish to get (we are talking about 1.5-2.5 T of rows) :( .